# react bootstrap causing TypeError Cannot read properties of null (reading "useState')

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I created a React app using Bootstrap, and it runs fine. I installed React Bootstrap and now I'm getting the error { TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState'). I'm assuming it's a version conflict somewhere, but can I verify and download the latest?

I get this error as soon as I run the site after installing react-bootstrap

I ran npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap from the cmd line

the package.json file has: items pertaining to bootstrap and react version

```
"dependecies": {
   "bootstrap":"^5.1.0",
    "react":"^17.0.2"


 }
```

Comment: I don't see `react-bootstrap` in the `dependencies`. Also, are you sure that you didn't remove an import by accident?

Comment: me either, I installed it several times. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and ran the command several times. I then created a React project using VS code just to see if it was something with VS '22 or not and when I ran the command [ npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap I received an error message of:  npm Err! Invalid Tag name "1.5.3:" Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.